# What causes high top_k_categorical_accuracy but low categorical_accuracy in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow, keras-2

I'm training a model using Conv2D and started to suddenly get a high **top k** categorical accuracy that is 1.0 but very low categorical accuracy (close to 0.006).

I have 108 different categories so the only thing I can think of that would cause it is that it somehow get's stuck on a single category this even though the dataset is extremely balanced.

So my question is very general:
What can cause high top_k_categorical_accuracy but low categorical_accuracy in Keras?

Comment: What's the value of `k`?

Comment: @Yu-Yang good question, it's standard so it's set to 5.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that the x-values where not normalised. As soon as I normalised them the top_k_categorical_accuracy became very low as expected.